# How to add configuration settings into _Layout.cshtml shared Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

We have this `StartUp` as follow that getting values from `appsettings.json`:

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();

    var environment = Configuration["ApplicationSettings:Environment"];
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings"));

    ...
}
```

And we also model called `AppSettings`

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

As I'm working on `/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` trying to inject this **Version** into this shared page, I could not do the code behind approach. How do inject this then?

**UPDATES 1 -**

In theory I could do like this if it's a page model:

```cs
public class _LayoutModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public string Version;
    public string Environment;

    public _LayoutModel(IOptions<AppSettings> appsettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appsettings.Value;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Environment = _appSettings.Environment;
        Version = _appSettings.Version;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like in the Controller, you can inject your services into the view too.

You can use `@inject` like this:

`@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettingsOptions`

or add `@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options` to the _ViewImports.cs and then inject the options in your layout like this:

`@inject IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettingsOptions`.

after that you can access your settings like: `@AppSettingsOptions.Value.Version`.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Hameed's answer, for Core 3.1:

AppSettings.Json:
`{  "Company": {"Name": "EvilCorp"}}`

_ViewImports.cshtml:
`@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`

_Layout.cshtml:
`@inject IConfiguration _config`

in the Razor html:
`<h1>@_config["Company:Name"]</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

you can access your settings using ViewData in your _layout.cshtml file.

In your _layout.cshtml file

```
<title>Version : @ViewData["Version"] | Environment : @ViewData["Environment"]</title>
```

But you have to set the value of ViewData in the .cshtml file of all pages you are sharing this layout like this

```
@model YourPageModel
@{
    ViewData["Environment"] = Model.Environment;
    ViewData["Version"] = Model.Version;
    Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Hope this helps :)